# Alloy fact NOT both properties

Tags: predicate, formal-methods, model-driven-development, fact, alloy

I have a piece of code in ALLOY I am trying to do a restaurant reservation system and I have this sig and relation between them.

```
abstract sig Table{
breakfast: one breakFast,
lunch: one Lunch,
dinner: one Dinner
}

sig Free{

}

sig Reserved{

}

sig breakFast {
breakfastfree:one Free,
breakfastReserved:one Reserved
}

sig Lunch {
Lunchfree:one Free,
LunchReserved:one Reserved

} 

sig Dinner  {
Dinnerfree:one Free,
 DinnertReserved:one Reserved
}


fact{
all t1,t2 : Table | t1 != t2 => t1.breakfast != t2.breakfast
all t1,t2 : Table | t1 != t2 => t1.lunch != t2.lunch
all t1,t2 : Table | t1 != t2 => t1.dinner != t2.dinner

 }

 pred RealismConstraints []{

 #Table = 4

 }
  run RealismConstraints for 20
```

I want to put a fact that for breakfast it can be reserved or free NOT BOTH and in lunch and dinner the same thing any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, the way you've constrained `breakfastfree` and `breakfastReserved` it will always be both. You need to use `lone` (no object or one):

```
sig breakFast {
  breakfastfree:lone Free,
  breakfastReserved:lone Reserved
}
```

Then, you could write the fact:

```
fact{
  all t: Table | let breakf = t.breakfast |
    #(breakf.breakfastfree+breakf.breakfastReserved) = 1
}
```

or, simpler, just:

```
sig breakFast {
  breakfastfree: lone Free,
  breakfastReserved: lone Reserved
}
{
  #(breakfastfree+breakfastReserved) = 1
}
```

However, I'd suggest that you just go with something like

```
sig breakFast {
    breakfastReserved: lone Reserved
}
```

and treat `no breakfastReserved` as "free". You don't need any further facts then.

Comment: in the last section you mean i should take out the free signature and keep only reserved and if it is not pointing on the reserved it is free?

Comment: if i do the last section as you mentioned i got some dinner alone without a relation with a table its like i lose my table proprites

Comment: If I understand you correctly, then I find the same behaviour in the original model (maybe you have to enumerate some solutions). If you wish all breakfasts etc. connected to a table you should use additional facts like "Table.breakfast = breakFast", "Table.lunch = Lunch" etc.

Comment: no what i mean is if i take out the free sig or sig breakFast {
  breakfastfree: lone Free,
  breakfastReserved: lone Reserved
}
{
  #(breakfastfree+breakfastReserved) = 1
} in the model some breakfasts or dinner or lunch without a table pointing to them

Comment: I think we mean the same. Try adding the facts I've given in my previous comment. If they don't help, you'd have to clarify your problem a bit.

Comment: perfect it works great thank you for your help and fast replies